# Fatal error: Cannot re-assign auto-global variable _POST in C:\xampp\htdocs\KSC\action.php on line 122

Tags: php, function, post

```
## Heading ##

function uang($_POST['hari'],$_POST['jamm'],$_POST['jams'],$_POST['id'],$_POST['jamm']){
}
```

Comment: You're mixing function definition with function call. It's time to read a [manual](http://php.net/functions)

Comment: you get out of life what you put into it...

Comment: Just access the `$_POST` in the function. `$_POST` is global. `function uang() {` and all `$_POST` will be accessible already.

Comment: ok thanks for the comment, now it work.